# Assign object[key] to a temp variable in a javascript "for...in" loop?

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I'm working on a JS to show different messages depending on the current url's hash.
Now, that's all working, but I was wondering what the best way would be to access my messages (They'll be coded into a .js file)

At the moment, I have the messages stored in a object like this:

```
popups = {
    TemplateMessage: {
        title: "Template Popup Title", 
        message: "This is a template popup message! Copy this to add a message.",
        modal: true
    },
    AnotherMessage: {
        title: "another title", 
        message: "message.",
        modal: true
    } /* etc */
};
```

the way I'm accessing these messages is with a "for in:  loop, as follows:

```
for (key in popups) {
    //Do something with...
    popups[key].title;
    popups[key].message;
    popups[key].modal;
}
```

But would it be more efficient to assign popups[key] to a temporary variable?
Like:

```
var p;
for (key in popups) {
    p = popups[key];
    //Do something with...
    p.title;
    p.message;
    p.modal;
}
```

This is all relatively small-scale at the moment and it wouldn't matter a lot (if anything at all) at this stage, but what if you have, say, 25 different objects with 50 properties on each of them?
I guess my real question would be, is there a (relatively) significant difference in obtaining a variable from a temp variable, or from a object in a object?

I'm not quite sure how to properly test this, any suggestions?

Comment: You can test things like this yourself easily at http://jsperf.com

Comment: @JamesAllardice Done: http://jsperf.com/tempvarforin
Apparently, it is faster to assign a temporary variable, after all...

Gotta keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Yeah it's a useful site. Just don't start using it all the time for micro-optimizations when you should probably focus on readability and maintainability of your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is indeed faster to assign your `object[key]` to a temporary variable in `for-in` loops with large objects, as seen in [this jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/tempvarforin). That way, you won't have to obtain `object[key]` for every property of the object.