# javascript "less than" if statement failing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is my function:

```
function reCalculate(i) {
    document.getElementById("Q" + i).value = document.getElementById("C" + i).value - document.getElementById("QA" + i).value;

    if (document.getElementById("Q" + i).value < 0) {
        document.getElementById("Q" + i).value = 0;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("Q" + i).value < document.getElementById("E" + i).value && document.getElementById("Q" + i).value != 0) {
        alert(document.getElementById("Q" + i).value + " is less than " + document.getElementById("E" + i).value + "?");
        document.getElementById("Q" + i).value = document.getElementById("E" + i).value;
    }
    document.getElementById("Q" + i).value = Math.ceil(document.getElementById("Q" + i).value);
}
```

It checks Q, if it's less than 0, it makes it 0. Then, if it's not 0, but it's less than E, it makes it E. For some reason this function works UNLESS Q is a double digit number.

For example, if Q is 7 and E is 2, then it will leave Q at 7. However, if Q is 10 and E is 2, for some reason it thinks that 10<2, and it changes Q to 2!

Am I missing something here??

Comment: Please cache your DOM elements to variables. Using getById each time reaches back into the DOM and is costly in performance.

Comment: Good point, I fixed that, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pull the `.value` of an element it returns a string. `'10'<'2'` will return true.

You can simply do a parseInt/parseFloat on the value, ala

```
var q = parseInt(document.getElementById("Q"+i).value,10)
```

Comment: You should use a radix `parseInt(x,10)`

Answer (score 4):

Thats because it is considering your `Q` as a **string** while comparing.

Try the following instead:

```
function reCalculate(i){

    var Z = document.getElementById, P = parseInt; 

    var qElem = Z("Q"+i);
    var q = P(qElem.value, 10);
    var c = P(Z("C"+i).value, 10);
    var qa = P(Z("QA"+i).value, 10);
    var e = P(Z("E"+i).value, 10);

    q = c - qa;

    if (q < 0) qElem.value = 0;

    if (q < e && q != 0){
        alert(q+" is less than "+e+"?");
        qElem.value = e;
    }

    qElem.value = Math.ceil(q);
}
```

Comment: tell the poster how to fix it!

Comment: @epascarello - Was formatting the code before posting it.. :-)

Comment: A nice sidenote: Aside from shorter code, using `var Z = document.getElementById;` actually makes the code more efficient. [Same principle as this here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451729/assign-objectkey-to-a-temp-variable-in-a-javascript-for-in-loop)

Answer (score 1):

May be you should do a

```
parseFloat(document.getElementById("Q"+i).value)
```

to make sure you are comparing numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing *strings* not numbers. Use the unary `+` to convert to a number:

```
if (+document.getElementById("Q" + i).value < +document.getElementById("E" + i).value ...)
```

You should use variables by the way:

```
var input_one = document.getElementById("Q" + i).value,
    input_two = document.getElementById("E" + i).value;

if (+input_one < +input_two) {

}
```

Comment: For the record it isn't comparing by length. I'm not quite sure what is is comparing by, though. (`'10'` is longer than `'2'`, however `'10' < '2'` evaluates to true)