# JavaScript input validation - unexpected results

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this event listener function

```
document.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('mileage-validation')) {
        if (document.getElementById('warningMileage').value > document.getElementById('scheduledMileage').value) {                
            document.getElementById('mileageError').classList.toggle('hidden');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('mileageError').classList.toggle('hidden');
        }
    }
})
```

with the following markup in a razor view

```
            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Maintenance.ScheduledMileage) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Maintenance.ScheduledMileage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control mileage-validation", id = "scheduledMileage" } })</li>
            <li>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Maintenance.ScheduledMileage, null, new { @class = "validation-error" })</li>

            <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Maintenance.WarningMileage) @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Maintenance.WarningMileage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control mileage-validation", id = "warningMileage" } })</li>
            <li>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Maintenance.WarningMileage, null, new { @class = "validation-error" })
                <span class="validation-error hidden" id="mileageError">Warning Mileage should be less than Scheduled Mileage.</span>
            </li>
```

I'm trying to front end validate that the WarningMileage value is less than the ScheduledMileage value (displaying an error if false) before the user submits.

1. **Test** - input 10 in Scheduled Mileage field with 0 in Warning Mileage field 
   **Result** - error is display 
   [image]

   > wrong
2. **Test** - input 9 in Warning Mileage field with 10 still in Scheduled Mileage field
   **Result** - error is hidden
   [image]

   > correct
3. **Test** - Go back to Scheduled Mileage field and increase value to 11
   **Result** - error is displayed (but warning mileage is less than scheduled mileage!)
   [image]

   > wrong

Hope this makes sense, no doubt it's something silly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.classList.toggle(className)` removes `className` if it exists or adds it otherwise, use `.add(className)` and `.remove(className)` instead.

Comment: Yeah that was my first approach, still shows the error message when warning mileage is less than scheduled mileage sometimes. I've also tried using addEventListener('input' just gave different unexpected results smh

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here [javascript "less than" if statement failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056878/javascript-less-than-if-statement-failing)
"You can simply do a parseInt/parseFloat on the value"